# Issue posting large text via textarea

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to send large text around 1000 characters using textarea. When I send around 300 characters it works perfectly fine but when I send 1000 characters via POST to PHP, I am unable to send.

```
<textarea rows="5" name="test_desc"> 1000 characters of text goes here ... </textarea>
```

I tried different solutions which I found over internet but in vain
Ex. I increased post_max_size from 8M to 128M. Also increased memory_limit to 128M from 32M.

Also when 1000 characters it shows

404 Page Not Found

The page you requested was not found.

But when I decrease the size it works fine.

All my code is hosted on a server. 
I am not sure if I am missing something here.

Any alternative solution to send large text would also be great.

Kindly let me know if any further information is required.

Any help in this regards will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any errors in the log file?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? Are you saving it to a database? maybe there is a column constraint on the size.

Comment: change you data type text in your db , may be you have limit in you database for that field, so remove the limit and make it text

Comment: 1000 characters is not "large text"

Comment: yes I am saving it to DB. Also in my DB the column accommodates 1000 characters. I mean I have given varchar 1000.

Comment: varchar 1000 may not accomodate 1000 character text if it is in unicode. Try to use text field as @ZIP suggested and see if it works. Also note before MySQL 5.0.3 there was a 255 character limit for varchar

Comment: @bansi I changed it to 'text' but still it doesnot work. I don't think the problem is with DB. I think the problem is with HTTP POST. Because I tried printing some output just when the function starts. But it says ' 404 Page Not Found The page you requested was not found. ' But when I decrease the number of characters it works fine

Comment: don't think any server may have restriction on 1000 characters posted. may be there is something wrong with some other part of the code. check your httpd logs. you can find some useful info there.

Answer (score 0):

The length of a `VARCHAR` column is fixed to the length that you declare when you create the table. The length can be any value from 0 to 255.

For example, VARCHAR(30) can hold up to 30 characters.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY column_name TEXT;
```

Comment: The limit is 0 to 65,535 in 5.0.3 and later versions.

Comment: I changed it to text but still no use, thanks for the correction though. I don't think the issue is with DB, I think it is something to do with HTTP

Answer (score 0):

Check for PHP.ini

```
max_input_vars
```

and

`post_max_size`